# Sort by different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

I have this data, in a table `categories`

```
id | name | post_count
 1 | A    | 10
 2 | B    | 15
 3 | C    | 8
 4 | D    | 14
 5 | E    | 1
 6 | F    | 20
```

I want to fetch the top 4 categories, by `post_count`, and order them by `name`.

If I do

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY post_count DESC LIMIT 4
```

I'll get the categories in order: `F, B, D, A`, while I want `A, B, D, F`

Is this possible with a single SQL query? How can I do this?

Comment: Why so many database tags? Do you want this to be compatible across all those different DBs? If so, it helps to specify versions ... MySQL 3.x or PostgreSQL 7.1 are extremely different in capabilities to PostgreSQL 9.2 or MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM 
               categories ORDER BY 
               post_count DESC LIMIT 4) AS A
ORDER BY name
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c482c/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from (

SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY post_count DESC LIMIT 4)a
order by name
```

Comment: I dont get those random -1 sometimes. The same answer above got a +1 and its correct. Stop hating on each other we are here to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from categories
    order by post_count desc
    limit 4
) s
order by name
```